# Marketing Cloud Connect - change email address and Username of the API User

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, marketing-cloud-connect, servicecloud

Is there any problem with changing the username and email of the integration user (API User)  between Marketing Cloud and Service Cloud (The integration is through Marketing Cloud Connect)?"

Does the integration fail or something if I change those user data?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the Marketing Cloud API User, you would just need to login to Salesforce after the change, go to the Marketing Cloud tab, click "Configure Marketing Cloud Connector" and then click the "Change API User" link and log back in with the Marketing Cloud API User credentials. This will re-authenticate the API connection.

If you are talking about changing the username of the Salesforce System User in Marketing Cloud, this will disrupt the integration. You would need to either change the username back to what it was originally, or break the connection in Marketing Cloud and re-setup the integration.